# Run migrations from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there a way to run rake commands for db:migrate and db:rollback on the console?

It sucks to wait for the rails environment to load!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

## Rails <= 4

This will allow you to migrate without reloading the whole rails environment:

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "db/migrate"
```

and rollback:

```
# 3 is the number of migrations to rollback, optional, defaults to 1
ActiveRecord::Migrator.rollback "db/migrate", 3
```

## Rails >= 5 (thanks to @gssbzn, his answer is below)

Migrate :

```
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").migrate
```

And rollback :

```
# 3 is the number of migrations to rollback, optional, defaults to 1
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").rollback 3
```

Comment: Note that if you're using Mongoid, it's the same: `Mongoid::Migrator.migrate "db/migrate"`

Comment: This is perfect to add to your test_helper.rb in Rails apps

Comment: Received  error, bash: ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate: command not found... using Rails 2.3.18, ruby 1.9.3p551, Now executed after executing the command inside the rails console.

Comment: In case for some weird reasons your migrations aren't located in `'db/migrate'`, use `ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.migrations_paths` in its place

Comment: This is correct for Rails 4, but doesn't work for later versions

Comment: See @gssbzn's answer for compatibility with rails 5.2+

Comment: Rollback for above 5 - `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").rollback` - not mentioned but also works

Comment: This worked for Rails 5 using this command
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate "db/migrate"

Comment: For newer Rails versions, you also need to pass `schema_migration`: `ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new(ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths, ActiveRecord::Base.connection.schema_migration)`

Answer (score 125):

In the console:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

To update your `schema.rb` file after running migrations from the console, you must run `rails db:migrate`

Comment: @WestonGanger how?

Comment: @nruth  not sure that weston is correct here. I find that any time I run these commands, then I might have to do `reload!` to get the effect in the console, and having finished with the console, as long I exit the console, I do rails db:migrate, and it migrates them, and updates db/schema.rb .  Really good to look at db/schema.rb .  it shows all your tables.  `rails db:migrate` updates `schema.rb` for you, at least I think that's what i've found.

Comment: @WestonGanger care to comment?(as your comment is under question)

Comment: @barlop @nruth. The migration occurs as soon as this command is run and changes the database, the schema however will not be updated. Running `rails db:migrate` can automatically update the schema. However this is an extra step that is not in the answer.

Comment: @WestonGanger yeah but since you can do rails db:migrate, that's not manually updating the schema.rb file. That's automatically updating it.

Answer (score 32):

Another way that I find neater to just run some migration command from console is this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :foo do |t|
    t.string  :bar
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

This has the advantage that the contents inside the block is compatible with just copy and pasting random contents from a real migration file / `schema.rb`.

Comment: I've found this really helpful in diagnosing some db-specific issues with migrations. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

For rails 5.2 the accepted answer has been removed and replaced with

```
ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate").migrate
```

Please be aware as this may also change for future versions of rails as they work to add multiple database connections

Answer (score 14):

For Rails 5 and Rails 6:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.migrate
```

For Rails 3 and Rails 4:

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate 'db/migrate'
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Rails 5 & 6, because it uses existing methods to get the migration context (instantiating it directly may not be reliable).

Answer (score 7):

I needed to pretend a migration was run to unblock a deploy, this can be done with:

```
class Mig < ActiveRecord::Base; self.table_name = 'schema_migrations';end
Mig.create! version: '20180611172637'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the %x[command]

```
%x[rake db:migrate]
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose to not have to wait for rails to load.

Comment: @rafamvc yes agreed! That's why I think Benoit's answer is better :)

Answer (score 1):

## To run single migration

ActiveRecord::Migration.add_column(:table_name, :column_name, :data_type)

## To run all migrations

ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate('db/migrate')

## To rollback n migrations

ActiveRecord::Migrator.rollback('db/migrate', n)

Comment: Doesn't work with Rails 7. Use ActiveRecord::MigrationContext.new("db/migrate") instead

Answer (score 0):

I created a method in my .irbrc file that runs migrations then reloads the console:

```
def migrate
  if defined? Rails::Console # turn off info logging for Rails 3
    old_log_level = ActiveRecord::Base.logger.try(:sev_threshold)
    ActiveRecord::Base.logger.sev_threshold = Logger::WARN
  end
  reload! && migations_ran = true if ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(Rails.root.join("db/migrate")).any?
  ActiveRecord::Base.logger.sev_threshold = old_log_level if defined? old_log_level
  migations_ran ||= nil # useful exit status
end
```

See the entire file here: https://gist.github.com/imme5150/6548368